# How do I make Infinite Scroll to top with js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

There is an example of infinite scroll to bottom.

```js
  var $ol = document.querySelector("ol");
    
    function load_more() {
      var html = "";
      
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) html += '<li></li>';
      $ol.innerHTML += html;
    }
    
    $ol.addEventListener("scroll", function() { 
      if ($ol.scrollHeight - $ol.scrollTop === $ol.clientHeight) 
        load_more();
    });
```

```html
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
```

There is an jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/n5o82orb/)

How do I make infinite scroll like this but to top with js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `$ol.scrollTop === 0` you can check if the `ol` is scrolled to the top. scollTop is always 0 when in the most upper position.

Also changed the loadMore function so it appends the new element to the start of the element with `$ol.prepend(document.createElement('li'))`

Last I added `$ol.scrollTop = firstEl.offsetTop;` in the loadmore function to automaticly scroll to the element that was previously the first element.

I reversed your `OL` so it's easier to see new items are loaded. This is not necessary of course.

```js
var $ol = document.querySelector("ol");

//Call this function onload so new content gets loaded and scrolling upwards become available.
load_more();

//Add event listner that triggers function when the element is scrolled to the top.
$ol.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if ($ol.scrollTop === 0)
    load_more();
});

//Load more items.
function load_more() {
  //Get the current first element.
  var firstEl = $ol.firstElementChild;

  //prepend the new elements.
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $ol.prepend(document.createElement('li'))
  }

  //scroll to the previous first element.
  $ol.scrollTop = firstEl.offsetTop;
}
```

```css
ol {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<ol reversed>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I like this solution. Its exactly what I need. But I reoppened this question and still see no "Mark as answer" button under your answer. Please try to remove this answer and make new answer for this question again.

Comment: @mr_blond Glad this works for you, however the question is still closed (2 votes to reopen now) so that's the reason why you can't accept and it's also the reason I can't post another answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is through the use of `IntersectionObserver`.

```js
const firstOptions = {
    threshold: 1,
    rootMargin: '100px'
}

const firstCardObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries)=>{
    const firstCard  = entries[0]

    if(!firstCard.isIntersecting) return

    loadCardsAtStart()

    firstCardObserver.unobserve(firstCard.target)
    firstCardObserver.observe(document.querySelector('.card:first-child'))

}, firstOptions)

firstCardObserver.observe(document.querySelector('.card:first-child'))
```

The `rootMargin` here plays and important role as it prevents the cards from loading in an infinite loop.

Also, make sure you use `prepend()` inside your `loadCardsAtStart()` to insert the newly created cards at the top.

Refer to this [video by WebDevSimplified](https://youtu.be/2IbRtjez6ag) in which he does the same thing but for infinite scroll to bottom.